# Screws in my base moulding

Tags: trim

I just hired an electrician to add electrical outlets to our older house. We decided to add our outlets to the base moulding because our house is an older lath and plaster construction.

When the electrician reattached the base moulding, he appeared to use screws to attach the base moulding vs. using nails. Not only that, he appeared to damage the quarter round moulding in the process. See attached picture.

Is this normal? Or did my electrician really mess up?

Thanks in advance for any experience and insights that people can provide!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your electrician is not a finish carpenter. Nobody competent would screw base like that.

All is not lost, however. Just make sure the screw heads are sunk below the surface of the wood. Get some wood filler/spackle (anything will do). Sand flat. Refill if you have divots. Prime. Paint.

It looks like the cap on the base was either attached badly or not attached at all. Do it over to match the line it had before. Caulk that gap before paint and it'll all be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Quick follow-up: covering up the screws will make it look nicer, but I'm wondering: wouldn't it make it more difficult for someone in the future to remove the base moulding, particularly someone who doesn't expect it to be screwed in?

Regarding the cap hanging off, it wasn't completely reattached yet, so that's expected. Good eye though.

Comment: It's absolutely true that someone in the future wouldn't expect screws. So in the unlikely event of future removal, they'd either figure it out and unscrew them, or they'd break the base trying. Good news for them is that the flat stock the base is made of is easily replaced. If you really cared, though, feel free to nail normally and remove the screws. Karma might reward you for it.